# Java AES Encryption - Sending initialization vector between Client and Server

Tags: java, encryption, aes, initialization-vector

I'm generating the initialization vector on the Client side where the messages are encrypted then sent to server together with the vector for decrypt.

**Client Code:**

```
            String key1 = "1234567812345678";
        byte[] key2 = key1.getBytes();


        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key2, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] iv = cipher.getIV();

        String text = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encrypted);

        System.out.println("Encrypted info: " + text);

        bytebuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        bytebuf.clear();

        // send iv

        bytebuf.put(iv);
        bytebuf.flip();
        while(bytebuf.hasRemaining()) {
            nBytes += client.write(bytebuf);
            System.out.println("Iv sent!");
        }

        bytebuf.clear();
        bytebuf.put(text.getBytes());

        bytebuf.flip();

        while(bytebuf.hasRemaining()) {
            nBytes += client.write(bytebuf);
        }
```

**Server Code**

```
            LOGGER.info("Confirming write");

        byte[] iv = buf.array();

        LOGGER.info("Data packet found as {}", iv);


        LOGGER.info("Confirming write");
        String data = new String(buf.array());

        LOGGER.info("Data packet found as {}", data);


        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        String key1 = "1234567812345678";
        byte[] key2 = key1.getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key2, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");


        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, ivspec);

        byte[] encrypted = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(data);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

        System.out.println("Decrypted Info: " + new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long
```

It seems that if I allocate 1024 bytes for example to the buffer, a 32 sized byte[] is sent to the server, but a 1024 sized byte[] will be generated on the server:

```
Data packet found as [-55, 119, 34, -19, -33, -20, -67, -77, 54, -111, 14, 94, 73, 98, 34, -7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,..................
```

Am I even on the right path?

Comment: Found the problem, I will edit the answer with the solution

Answer (score 3):

Instead of allocating 1024 bytes, I had to allocate 16 for the Initialization Vector instead.

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
```

Forgot to read the socketchannel for the following messages:

```
            buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
        buf.clear();
        socket.read(buf);
```